# Vagrant commissioner shell command complains about sudo

Tags: apache, centos, vagrant

So I have a CentOS 6.2 virtual machine that I am setting up and want to run a shell command. I'm trying to start apache and mysql once the machine has fully booted. The vagrant user is in the sudoers file and I can execute sudo commands starting ssh via "vagrant ssh".

When I add the shell command to the vagrant file it complains about the vagrant user not being in the sudoers file.

Does anyone have an idea as to why this would happen?

I know I can have the server start apache automatically, but I need it to start after the shared folders have been mounted. I'm using the /vagrant folder to store the vhosts and the content that apache serves.

Comment: Resolved this by adding the commands that I needed directly to the sudoers file for the vagrant user to launch.

Comment: Seems like there should be a better way to handle this.  I'm running into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Vagrant not only needs to be in the sudores file but must be configured to be used without a password. like this

vagrant ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

see here:
https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/boxes/base.html

Scroll down to the section on password-less sudo

Hope this helps!